# Documentation for CodeAuthzpComputeImageHash

Tags: winapi

Can anyone point me to documentation for `CodeAuthzpComputeImageHash()` in advapi32.dll?

I can't seem to find documentation anywhere.

Comment: My tests show the output of CodeAuthzpComputeImageHash() is an MD5 hash on Windows 2003. MD5 is totally insecure. non-starter for using SRP Hash Rules to protect old 2003 boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't find documentation for this function is that this function is undocumented.

Not all winapi functions are documented, unfortunately.

There is a mention of the function at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786941(v=WS.10).aspx, though:

> ItemData (REG_BINARY). The actual hash to the file. This value should always be 16 bytes and is generated with a call to CodeAuthzpComputeImageHash().

Also, you can use a trampoline to hook the function, and if you know how to cause it to be executed, you can then try to see its arguments and return type.

Also, try searching at WINE if they have implemented it. Ask in their mailing list. Since they try to implement winapi, they need to implement the undocumented parts, too, there's a good chance they have some understanding about the function.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The link you posted is where I found out about the function, I'm trying to generate SRP Hash Rules. I did a bit of reading on using a trampoline and that's a bit beyond anything I've ever tried. I'll give it a shot though. I will also inquire at the WINE mailing list.

Comment: OK, also, if you think my answer is a valid answer (in that there is no documentation to be found), you can accept it (the green tick).